# Equal spacing between lines of NSAttributedString with multiple font sizes for a UILabel in iOS 6

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, nsattributedstring, spacing

I have a multiple lines UILabel with attributed text.

All the lines in the text are of the same font, but each line is of a different font size.

I'm trying to achieve the exact same vertical space between each line.

However what is being displayed has variable spaces. It is as if something is adding a vertical margin to the font based on the font size.

```
CGFloat y = 0;

NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSArray *linesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One I\n",
                       @"Two I\n",
                       @"Three I\n",
                       @"Four I\n",
                       @"Five I\n", nil];

CGFloat fontSize = 10.0;

for(NSString *line in linesArray) {

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedLine = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:line];
    NSInteger stringLength=[line length];
    [attributedLine addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                              value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:fontSize]
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength)];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.0f;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    [attributedLine addAttributes:@{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle} range:NSMakeRange(0, stringLength)];


    [attString appendAttributedString:attributedLine];

    fontSize += 10.0;
}

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.attributedText = attString;
[label sizeToFit];
CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
newFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 40;
newFrame.origin.y = y;
newFrame.origin.x = 0;
label.frame = newFrame;
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Any suggestions on the code I should use in order for it to display no space at all between each line of text?

Answer (score 3):

I have been doing something similar, so maybe you could try something like this (typed in browser, watch out!):

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setAlignment: NSTextAlignmentRight];
[style setLineSpacing:0];

for(NSString *line in linesArray) {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *subStyle = [style mutableCopy];
    [subStyle setMaximumLineHeight:10]; // play around with this value <-----

    NSDictionary *attributes = 
    @{
      NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:fontSize],
      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
    };

    [attString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:line attributes: attributes]];

    fontSize += 10.0;
}
```

Comment: In the attributes dictionary, changing "paragraphStyle" to "style" worked for me. I have a slightly different case where the paragraph spacing is needed on sentences in a long string not in an array so no for loop necessary.